# Google sheet API - reset auto numbered sheet name

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm using google sheet api with this logic for each request:

- create a sheet,
- add custom query there (custom formula),
- fecth query results,
- delete the created sheet.

The creation code is a follow with Laravel:

```
class GoogleSheetsApiClientManager {

    private $client;//authorized API client.
    private $service = null;

    public function __construct($apiOptions) {
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName(array_get($apiOptions, 'application_name', 'Google Sheets API PHP'));
        $this->client->setScopes(array_get($apiOptions, 'scope', Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS));
        $this->client->setAuthConfig(array_get($apiOptions, 'credential_path'));
        $this->client->setAccessType('offline');

        $this->service = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);
    }

    public function addNewSheet($spreadsheetId, $hidden = false, $sheetName = false){
        try {
            $properties = [
                'hidden' => $hidden
            ];
            if($sheetName){
                $properties['title'] = $sheetName;
            }
            $body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
                'requests' => [
                    'addSheet' => [
                        'properties' => $properties
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
            $result = $this->service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
            return $result;
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            Log::error('Add new sheet using Google Sheet API : '.$exception->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And the call is like:

```
$apiOptions = [
            'application_name' => 'My app name',
            'credential_path' => __DIR__.'/service_account-secret.json'
        ];
$googleSheetManager = new GoogleSheetsApiClientManager($apiOptions);
$spreadsheetId = '--theSpreasheetId--';
$mySheet = $googleSheetManager->addNewSheet($spreadsheetId);
```

The issue : Each time I create new sheet, its name is based on last created one. eg: last sheet name is `sheet5`, even `sheet5` has been deleted I got new sheet with name `sheet6`.

What I would like to have is the minimal possible name, meaning if `sheet5` & `sheet4` are not there (but `sheet3` is present), I would like a new name `sheet4`, not an endless incremented name

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @jess question updated